# SQL select closest values from multiple columns and order by the best

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has 8 columns, let say:
My table name is x_table and columns: id, score_1, score_2, score_3, score_4, score_5, score_6,  score_7..

Each score_* columns has a score from 0 to 10. Then let say I want to search my table  with the following values:

score_1=7, score_2=9, score_3=6, score_4=9, score_5=10, score_6=8, score_7=4.

How do I select this table and display the results according to the best closest values

This below query doesn't give 100% of what I need:

```
SELECT *
FROM xc_t
WHERE t_id <> 0
    AND t_category1 BETWEEN 0
        AND 11
    AND t_category2 BETWEEN 0
        AND 11
    AND t_category3 BETWEEN 0
        AND 11
    AND t_category4 BETWEEN 0
        AND 11
    AND t_category5 BETWEEN 0
        AND 11
    AND t_category6 BETWEEN 0
        AND 11
    AND t_category7 BETWEEN 0
        AND 11
ORDER BY abs(t_category1 - 6)
    ,abs(t_category2 - 6)
    ,abs(t_category3 - 9)
    ,abs(t_category4 - 2)
    ,abs(tea_category5 - 9)
    ,abs(t_category6 - 4)
    ,abs(t_category7 - 10) limit 0
    ,20
```

Comment: GL is too polite to mention, but this kind of problem is actually symptomatic of appallingly poor design. GL's solution is but a miserable sticking plaster.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do.  So for a given table,  you want to select the row that contains a number closes to your input?  So, for example, if I had a table "Payments", you're looking for a way to select the payment that was closest to $20?

Comment: "best closest values" -> closest to what? Also your table has column score_1 to score_7 while your example doesn't use any of them. Please show actual database structure and actual code, we don't know your system, it's hard for us to make a connection if your given information doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `greatest()`:

```
select t.*, greatest(score_1, score_2, . . ., score_8) as max_score
from t
order by max_score desc;
```

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
order by (abs(score_1 - @score_1) +
          abs(score_2 - @score_2) +
          . . .
          abs(score_7 - @score_7)
         )
```

Comment: Not actually, I need to specify values on each score to search the closest values from the database: like  select t.*, greatest(score_1=6, score_2=7, . . .,) as max_score
from t
order by max_score desc;